# Function inside chrome extension script is returning the wrong value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a function for a chrome extension that gets the status ('loading' or 'complete') of the current tab.

currentTabId is a global variable.

```
function getTabStatus() {
    var tabStatus = "foobar";

    chrome.tabs.get(currentTabId, function(tab) {
        tabStatus = tab.status;
    });

    return tabStatus;
}
```

I would expect this function to return 'loading' or 'complete' but it's returning 'foobar'.

If I set a breakpoint in Chrome developer tools on the 5th line (tabStatus = tab.status), the function has already returned 'foobar' but still stops at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to asynchronous programming. `chrome.tabs.get` executes, but `return tabStatus` runs before `tabStatus = tab.status`. You need to arrange your code in such a way that it continues running from within the `chrome.tabs.get`.

What's going on is, `chrome.tabs.get` is passed a callback (your anonymous function `function(tab)`) to execute when it is done doing the `get`, so the code is `tabStatus = tab.status` is actually running after your code does the `return tabStatus`.

You need to rewrite your code sort of like this:

```
function getTabStatus() {
    var tabStatus = "foobar";

    chrome.tabs.get(currentTabId, function(tab) {
        tabStatus = tab.status;
        doSomething(tabStatus);
    });
}
```

Rather than doing a call-return style, you need to call another method that will continue the execution of your code.

The reason why this is done is so your code doesn't have to wait for `get` to execute before it continues running, sort of like multithreading. It allows your code to branch into two directions that can perform two different code paths at the same time, but some variables won't be in the correct scope, so that's when you encounter issues like this.

You can read more about asynchronous programming [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700330.aspx).

Comment: So are all (or most) Chrome api functions asynchronous?

Comment: Many API functions are asynchronous, this is because it can make your code faster in some cases, because it doesn't block other code from execution. Returning from inside the callback doesn't work, because the callback is another function, so you return from that, but you don't return all the way back to your original scope. Unfortunately there's no easy way to turn an asynchronous function into more of a call-return style format that you're probably used to.